# Windows Phone 7 Navigate To URL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigatetourl

I have a folder named `Views` and inside it I have pages I want to navigate to. There is a page inside this folder named "Y.XAML" so I'm trying to use:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Viev//Y.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/YourPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Failing that you can always try the more explicit `/ProjectName;component/Views/YourPage.xaml`

Answer (score 1):

1. You Navigate to "Viev" not "Views".
2. Its Views/Y.xaml not Views//Y.xaml

Other then that it should work. If not, provide more Information